# Setting spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri per end-point

Tags: spring, spring-security

I need to set the value of spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri per endpoint (it will be done in a rest interceptor which extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter), how can it be done?